# Why won't the Ready and BlockedReason values return in task model

Tags: rally

I am trying to return a list of tasks and include the Ready and BlockedReason values.   The below code is returning all the columns listed in 'configCfgs' except these 2.  Any ideas how to grab them?

```
this.grid = this.add({
    xtype: 'rallygrid',
    model: model,
    columnCfgs: ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'Ready', 'Blocked', 'BlockedReason', 'WorkProduct', 'Owner', 'Release', 'Iteration','Project'],
    columns: [
        { text: 'Test',  dataIndex: 'FormattedID', width: 20}
    ],
    storeConfig: {
        context: {
            projectScopeUp: false,
            projectScopeDown: true
        },
        filters: this._activeFilters
    }
});
```

Here is the complete function:

```
            launch: function launch() {
                Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
                    type: 'Task',
                    scope: this,
                    success: function(model) {
                        var project = Rally.environment.getContext().getProject().ObjectID;

                        var me = this;
                        var clearFiltersStoreConfig = {
                            listeners: {
                                load: function() {
                                    me._clearFilterInputs();
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        var filterContainer = {
                            width: 800,
                            xtype: 'container',
                            cls: 'filter-container',
                            layout: {
                                type: 'hbox'
                            },
                            items: [{
                                xtype: 'container',
                                items: [{
                                    xtype: 'button',
                                    width: 100,
                                    text: 'Reset Filters',
                                    handler: Ext.bind(this._resetFilters, this)
                                }],
                                flex: 1
                            },{
                                xtype: 'container',
                                layout: 'vbox',
                                items: [{
                                    xtype: 'container',
                                    cls: 'name-container',
                                    layout: 'hbox',
                                    items: [{
                                        id: 'nameTextField',
                                        labelWidth: 45,
                                        xtype: 'rallytextfield',
                                        fieldLabel: 'Name',
                                        storeConfig: clearFiltersStoreConfig,
                                        enableKeyEvents: true,
                                        listeners: {
                                            keypress: Ext.bind(this._enterKeyPressed("Name"), this)
                                        }
                                    },
                                    this._makeClearButton('nameTextField', 'Name')],
                                    flex: 1
                                }, {
                                    xtype: 'container',
                                    cls: 'owner-container',
                                    layout: 'hbox',
                                    items: [{
                                        id: 'ownerComboBox',
                                        labelWidth: 45,
                                        xtype: 'rallyusercombobox',
                                        fieldLabel: 'Owner',
                                        project: '/project/' + project,
                                        storeConfig: clearFiltersStoreConfig,
                                        listeners: {
                                            select: Ext.bind(this._optionSelected("Owner"), this)
                                        }
                                    },
                                    this._makeClearButton('ownerComboBox', 'Owner')],
                                    flex: 1
                                }],
                                flex: 1
                            }, {
                                xtype: 'container',
                                layout: 'vbox',
                                items: [{
                                    xtype: 'container',
                                    layout: 'hbox',
                                    items: [{
                                        id: 'releaseComboBox',
                                        xtype: 'rallyreleasecombobox',
                                        plugins: [],
                                        fieldLabel: "Release",
                                        autoSelect: false,
                                        labelWidth: 45,
                                        listConfig: {
                                            minWidth: 90,
                                            width: 90,
                                            itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<div class="timebox-name<tpl if="isSelected"> timebox-item-selected</tpl>">{formattedName}</div>')
                                        },
                                        storeConfig: clearFiltersStoreConfig,
                                        listeners: {
                                            select: Ext.bind(this._optionSelected("Release"), this)
                                        }
                                    },
                                    this._makeClearButton('releaseComboBox', 'Release')],
                                    flex: 1
                                }, {
                                    xtype: 'container',
                                    layout: 'hbox',
                                    items: [{
                                        id: 'iterationComboBox',
                                        xtype: 'rallyiterationcombobox',
                                        plugins: [],
                                        fieldLabel: "Iteration",
                                        labelWidth: 45,
                                        listConfig: {
                                            minWidth: 90,
                                            width: 90,
                                            itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<div class="timebox-name<tpl if="isSelected"> timebox-item-selected</tpl>">{formattedName}</div>')
                                        },
                                        storeConfig: clearFiltersStoreConfig,
                                        listeners: {
                                            select: Ext.bind(this._optionSelected("Iteration"), this)
                                        }
                                    },
                                    this._makeClearButton('iterationComboBox', 'Iteration')],
                                    flex: 1
                                }],
                                flex: 1
                            }]
                        };

                        this.add(filterContainer);
                        this.grid = this.add({
                            xtype: 'rallygrid',
                            model: model,
                            columnCfgs: ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'Ready', 'Blocked', 'BlockedReason', 'WorkProduct', 'Owner', 'Release', 'Iteration','Project'],
                            columns: [
                                { text: 'Test',  dataIndex: 'FormattedID', width: 20}
                            ],
                            storeConfig: {
                                context: {
                                    projectScopeUp: false,
                                    projectScopeDown: true
                                },
                                filters: this._activeFilters
                            }
                        });

                        var me = this;
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            me._loadLastFilters();
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: Please share the code where you instantiate your model and/or store.

Comment: I added the complete function

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure the Tasks that are displaying in your grid actually have values for these fields? I tested almost identical code and these columns display. However Ready only displays a check-mark if it = true, and obviously Blocked Reason needs a value. http://imgur.com/ChhAM5U

Comment: Thanks for looking into this...  Yes, I have confirmed there is a blocked reason and some have ready set to true.  Your image is showing the header for those columns, but I don't even see the header for those 2 columns.  Also, mine doesn't show the gear.

Comment: Here is an image of what mine looks like.  Is yours from a different version of the SDK?  Or a different xtype? http://imgur.com/UlC5wVQ

Comment: Here's my sample. It's really basic: https://gist.github.com/markwilliams970/9264169 . What does this look like when you load it?

Comment: Thanks again!  Ya yours is working and displaying it correctly.  I'll try to compare yours against mine tomorrow to see if I see anything that sticks out.

Comment: Try killing the columns parameter in your grid
. It's not needed here.     columns: [
        { text: 'Test',  dataIndex: 'FormattedID', width: 20}
    ],

Comment: Ok figured it out!  It was the version of the SDK causing the issue.  You were using 2.0rc2 and the one that was being used in it was 2.0p4.  I pulled that down from one of the github repos so not sure if that is older or what.  Regardless everything is working as expected.  Thanks again for all the assistance.